# Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range when naming a sheet

Tags: vba, excel, subscript

The following is an Excel Macro that I am trying to debug but I have never worked with these before.

The line `Set log = Sheets("Quote Log")` is being highlighted in yellow and the error is `Sheets("Quote Log")` = *Subscript out of range*

```
Sub Feasibility()

    Dim Feasibility As Workbook
    Dim FeasibilitySheet, log As Worksheet
    Dim row, rowSize, x As Integer
    Dim UAI, customer, today, prodNum, name As String

    Set log = Sheets("Quote Log")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If checkSelection() Then

        row = getSelectionRow()
        rowSize = getSelectionRowSize()

        For x = row To rowSize
            Set Feasibility = Workbooks.Open(Environ$("UserProfile") & "\My Documents\" & "QF-010 UMD Team Feasibility R1.xlsx")
            Set FeasibilitySheet = Feasibility.Sheets("Feasibility")

            UAI = log.Cells(x, 1)
            customer = log.Cells(x, 2)
            prodNum = log.Cells(x, 5)
            name = log.Cells(x, 6)
            today = log.Cells(x, 17)

           FeasibilitySheet.Range("B3") = customer
           FeasibilitySheet.Range("F3") = today
           FeasibilitySheet.Range("C4") = prodNum
           FeasibilitySheet.Range("C5") = name
           FeasibilitySheet.Range("D41") = today
           FeasibilitySheet.Range("D43") = today
           FeasibilitySheet.Range("E45") = today


            Feasibility.SaveAs Environ$("UserProfile") & "\My Documents\" & _
                 "Feasibility " & prodNum & " " & UAI & ".xls"

           Feasibility.Close


        Next

    End If

    ''''


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'RFI
End Sub
```

Comment: `1` You do not have a sheet with that name `2` If you can visually see it then either it has leading or trailing spaces  or it is in another workbook.

Comment: So the name should be the name of the file I am trying to make the macro on?

Comment: No. `Sheets("Quote Log")` is looking to pull a sheet named "Quote Log" from the `Sheets` collection (should be the `Worksheets` collection BTW) of whatever workbook is the active workbook, and the error tells you that there's no "Quote Log" sheet in that workbook. Either you have the wrong book active, or you mispelled the sheet name, or a user went in and renamed the sheet, or whatever. There's no "Quote Log" sheet in the `Sheets` collection.

Comment: That's good work on rubberduck @Mat'sMug :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks! Now I need it to be able to infer types from usage, and that inspection+quickfix will be complete! =)

Comment: I am now getting "Run-time error '438': Object  doesn't support this property or method on the following line: Set FeasibilitySheet = Feasibility.Workbook("Feasibility")

Comment: `Feasibility` is a `Workbook` object, it doesn't have a `Workbook` member. Do you not get intellisense/autocomplete when you type the dot after `Feasibility.`?

Comment: No, I do not get that when I type the dot.

Comment: You do not have as sheet `Feasibility` in the workbook `QF-010 UMD Team Feasibility R1.xlsx`. Open it manually and check.

Comment: `Sub Feasibility()` and then `Dim Feasibility As Workbook`? Bad idea. Not that you will get an error in your above code but like I said it is a bad idea. Change one of them

Comment: Correct, I only have one sheet and it is called Sheet1

Comment: So change `Set FeasibilitySheet = Feasibility.Sheets("Feasibility")` to `Set FeasibilitySheet = Feasibility.Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: The issue is that I did not write any of this code and have never worked with macros and I am trying to fix someone else's code that is broken

Comment: `The issue is that I did not write any of this code and have never worked with macros and I am trying to fix someone else's code that is broken – Mikayla S just now` Then you are in the wrong forum. :) You have 2 options `1` Learn VBA and then try fixing it `2` Hire someone to fix it.

Comment: Sorry but I will have to vote to close this question as "Too Broad"

Comment: Thank you! The code is now working.